# filter-out on shell output

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

There are four folders in my src directory: dir1, dir2, dir3, dir4.

```
PARSE_MODULES = $$(MODULES=$$(ls -l $1 | grep '^d' | awk '{print $$9}'); echo $$MODULES);
MODULES:=$(call PARSE_MODULES,src)
all:
    @echo $(MODULES)
```

Hence, this little piece of code outputs

```
dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4
```

Now, I add the following two lines before the `all` rule:

```
X:=dir1 dir3
MODULES:=$(filter-out $(X),$(MODULES))
```

The output remains unchanged, i.e., `filter-out` is not working as expected. However, if I manually define `MODULES`, I get the expected output:

```
MODULES:=dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4
X:=dir1 dir3
MODULES:=$(filter-out $(X),$(MODULES))
```

**Output:** `dir2 dir4`

Why is it impossible to process the output of `awk` in filter-out? Is there any way to do so?

Comment: What's the output of `$(words $(MODULES))` for these cases?

Comment: After applying filter-out, the output is 12 in the first case and 2 in the second one. It should be 2 in both cases...

Comment: Not sure but I don't think `MODULES` is being expanded as/when you think it is.  What is the output of `$(info MODULES=[$(MODULES)])` immediately before the `$(filter-out ...` command?  I suspect it might be something like `$(MODULES=$(ls -l src | grep '^d' | awk '{print $9}'); echo $MODULES);` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you have deferred expansion of the contents of `PARSE_MODULES` by using `$$`, so that it's being run by the shell in the recipe, not by make.

This:

```
PARSE_MODULES = $$(MODULES=$$(ls -l $1 | grep '^d' | awk '{print $$9}'); echo $$MODULES);
MODULES:=$(call PARSE_MODULES,src)
```

leaves the `MODULES` variable containing this text:

```
$(MODULES=$(ls -l src | grep '^d' | awk '{print $9}'); echo $MODULES);
```

Then when you use `$(MODULES)` in the recipe, it expands like this:

```
all:
        @echo $(MODULES=$(ls -l src | grep '^d' | awk '{print $9}'); echo $MODULES);
```

then the shell will run the command inside `$(...)` and echo the results.

When you try to filter out names like `dir1` etc. from the value of the make variable `MODULES`, nothing happens because the make variable `MODULES` contains the shell script itself, as text, it doesn't contain the results of executing the shell script.

I'm not sure why you are trying to do things in such an incredibly convoluted way, with so much escaping and using difficult to understand shell scripting.  Maybe there's a reason that your full environment needs something so complicated but you can *FAR* more easily implement the example above just using some basic make functions:

```
PARSE_MODULES = $(sort $(notdir $(patsubst %/.,%,$(wildcard $1/*/.))))

MODULES := $(call PARSE_MODULES,src)
```

Now the PARSE_MODULES is expanded by make, not by the recipe, and `filter-out` etc. will work fine on it.  Plus it's a lot simpler then doing a shell with grep and awk.

Comment: nice improvements with builtin features - notdir, patsubst, wildcard

Comment: Thank you. A very nice and understandable explanation. The reason for this "incredibly convoluted way" is easy: I am parsing config files where the user can manually exclude directories. This parsing is done in a shell script, which is why I did everything in shell.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the shell list `$(MODULES=$(ls -l src | grep '^d' | awk '{print $9}'); echo $MODULES)` is evaluated by the shell when the recipe of `all` is executed. This is too late. Try this, maybe:

```
PARSE_MODULES = $(shell ls -l $1 | grep '^d' | awk '{print $$9}')
MODULES       := $(call PARSE_MODULES,src)

X             := dir1 dir3
MODULES       := $(filter-out $(X),$(MODULES))

all:
    @echo $(MODULES)
```

Answer (score 1):

Minor simplification from OP version:

```
# possibly: find -maxdepth 1
PARSE_MODULES = $(shell find $1 -type d -printf "%P\n")
SKIP := dir1 dir3

MODS := $(call PARSE_MODULES,src)
FLTR := $(filter-out $(SKIP), $(MODS))

all:
    @echo MODS: $(MODS)
    @echo SKIP: $(SKIP)
    @echo FLTR: $(FLTR)
```

Output:

```
MODS: dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4
SKIP: dir1 dir3
FLTR: dir2 dir4
```